React Native Scroll View won't scroll all the way to the bottom (tried everything I could find)
I have decent experience with React but I'm a complete beginner in React Native. I'm making a basic card game app which just displays "cards" of various superheroes.
But the app just won't scroll all the way to the bottom. I have tried everything I could find online (it seems to be a very popular problem and yet there's no consistent solution to it T_T). I even tried replacing my ImageBackground components with plain Image components, still no luck.
I would be really grateful for any help at all.
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, SafeAreaView} from "react-native";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import MCUSpiderMan from "./assets/MCUSpiderMan.jpg"

import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={{width: "100%"}} contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "center", paddingBottom: 100, flexGrow: 1}}>
          <Text style = {styles.heading}>THE SPIDEY CARD GAME</Text>
          <Card charImage={MCUSpiderMan} charPoints={"+100"} charName={"MCU" +
              " Spider-Man"} charDesc={"The teenager who just can't catch a break. Well, at least we got Mr. Stark, right?"}
                charQuote={"Mr. Stark...I don't feel so good..."}/>
          <Card charImage={MCUSpiderMan} charPoints={"+100"} charName={"MCU" +
              " Spider-Man"} charDesc={"The teenager who just can't catch a break. Well, at least we got Mr. Stark, right?"}
                charQuote={"Mr. Stark...I don't feel so good..."}/>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#111",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  heading: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    fontSize: 48,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginVertical: 20
  },
})

export default App;

import {View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text} from "react-native";
const Card = ({charImage, charName, charPoints, charDesc, charQuote}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <ImageBackground source = {charImage} style={styles.imageBG} resizeMode={"cover"}>
                <View style = {styles.cardTop}>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>
                        {charName}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.cardBottom}>
                    <Text style={styles.points}>
                        Points: {charPoints}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.desc}>
                        {charDesc}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.quote}>
                        "{charQuote}"
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        width: "80%",
        height: "60%",
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
    imageBG: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 450,
        overflow: "hidden",
        borderTopColor: "#A71814",
        borderBottomColor: "#A71814",
        borderLeftColor: "#283278",
        borderRightColor: "#283278",
        borderWidth: 8,
        borderTopWidth: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 12,
        borderRadius: 8,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
    cardTop: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff8e5",
        opacity: 0.9,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderRadius: 2,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    cardBottom: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff8e5",
        opacity: 0.9,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 10,
        width: "95%",
        gap: 5,
    },
    heading: {
        fontWeight: "900",
        fontSize: 26,
    },
    points: {
        fontWeight: "900",
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    desc: {

    },
    quote: {
        fontWeight: "500",
    }
})

export default Card;

Thanks in advance.
PS: Also, if this is such a popular issue, why isn't there a foolproof solution? I came across FlatList but the documentation says it only differs in that it lazy loads components. That shouldn't cause performance improvements in just basic scrolling should it?

Figured it out and leaving this here for when inevitably someone will face the same issue.
Making the card a fixed height instead of a percentage height worked. Again, I'm a beginner so I'm not sure why, maybe someone else can take that up, but yeah
